# How to pass data from PHP to a custom uiComponent js class

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, knockoutjs

I have created a phtml template and I have hook it up with a custom uiComponent model. Then I use knockout to bind model data into the template.

This is working fine at the moment, the problem is I can't pass data from PHP into the JS module I have created.

This is what I have so far :

My layout.xml file to display the phtml template :

```
<block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Customer\Form" name="vendor_module_template" template="Vendor_Module::template.phtml">
<arguments>
    <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="types" xsi:type="array"/>
        <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="custom_component" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module/js/component</item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="template" xsi:type="string">path/to/template</item><!-- I can't access this from js -->
                    <item name="var1" xsi:type="string">some-value</item><!-- I can't access this from js -->
                    <item name="var2" xsi:type="string">some-other-value</item><!-- I can't access this from js -->
                </item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</arguments>
</block>
```

Then I have my phtml template :

```
<div data-block="refer-friend" data-bind="scope: 'custom_component'">
<form style="display: none;" data-bind="visible: true">
    <ul data-bind="foreach: friends, visible: friends().length > 0" class="hidden">
        <li>
            Email
            <input type="text" name="email" data-bind="value: email, disable: isSent" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <p data-bind="if: isSent"><?= __('Sent'); ?></p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <button  data-bind="disable: isSent">
                <!-- ko if: isSent -->
                <!-- ko i18n: 'Re-Send' --><!-- /ko -->
                <!-- /ko -->

                <!-- ko ifnot: isSent -->
                <!-- ko i18n: 'Send' --><!-- /ko -->
                <!-- /ko -->
            </button>
        </li>
    </ul>
</form>
</div>

<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{
    "[data-block='refer-friend']": {
        "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": <?= $block->getJsLayout();?>
    }
}
</script>
```

And then finally my component.js file

```
define([
'uiComponent',
'jquery',
'ko',
'underscore'
 ], function (Component, $, ko, _) {
'use strict';

function Friend(data) {
    this.email = ko.observable(data.email);
    this.isSent  = ko.observable(data.isSent);
};

return Component.extend({

    friends: ko.observableArray(),

    /**
     * @override
     */
    initialize: function () {

        console.log(this.options) ;
        this.friends.push(new Friend({email : 'friend1@example.com', isSent : true}));
        this.friends.push(new Friend({email : 'friend2@example.com', isSent : false}));

    },
});
});
```

This is all working fine except the fact that I can't access the configuration options I set from the layout xml file. 
How can this be done?

Also, I would like to use a knockout html template, which I have seen in the core that they also set from the layout xml but this is not working either when I try it.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

You were so close, you're just missing `this._super();` from the initialize function.

```
initialize: function () {
    this._super();
    console.log(this.var1);
    this.friends.push(new Friend({email : 'friend1@example.com', isSent : true}));
    this.friends.push(new Friend({email : 'friend2@example.com', isSent : false}));
},
```

[image]

`this._super();` will call the same function it's called in but belonging to the parent, so in this case it will call the initialize function of it's parent (probably `Component`). If we ran it inside a function named `test` it would call the `test` function of it's parent component.

To check how to access everything passed through to the component console log `this`.

Comment: This doesn't work for me.  The browser tries to load a "valueTest.js" file.  I think somehow the variable data has to be injected into the object returned by $block->getJsLayout()?

Comment: I've updated my answer, I completely missed the cause!

Answer (score 0):

I too have struggled with this (and am still struggling with how to set data in my PHP which is passed to my component)...

The answer is...
Just below "strict;" wrap your code inside another function:

```
return function(config) { ... return component.extend({...}); }
```

and the values you set in your .xml will be properties of the config object.